# how to update a DE with SMS responses

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

```
%%[ 
SET @MobileSendLogDE    = "MobileSendLog" 
SET @MOBILE_NUMBER_FIELD_LABEL   = "MobileNumber" 
SET @KEYWORD_FIELD_LABEL      = "Keyword" 
SET @UserInput_FIELD_LABEL = "UserInput"
SET @initialKeyword         = "SENDLOG" 
SET @UserInput      = Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)]) 
SET @mobileNumber      = Mobile_Number 

INSERTDATA(@MobileSendLogDE,@MOBILE_NUMBER_FIELD_LABEL,@mobileNumber,@KEYWORD_FIELD_LABEL,@initialKeyword,@UserInput_FIELD_LABEL,@UserInput)
]%%
```

This is not working. could any one please help me

Comment: I have made some changes to atleast know the syntax, here is the working code... this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to atleast know the syntax, here is the working code... this might be helpful

```
%%[ Var @msg
if (Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(1)]) == "STEP2") then
Set @msg = "What is your last name"
else
Set @msg = "We're sorry, that's incorrect"
endif ]%%
%%= v(@msg) =%%
%%[UpsertData('SmsSendLog_Testing', 1, 'MobileNumber', MobileNumber, 'UserInput',@msg)]%%
```